# Downloading multiple concurrent files in Python

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm going to write a downloader program in Python that accepts URLs from multiple users and downloads them:

```
def download_file(url):
    local_filename = url.split('/')[-1]
    try:
        with requests.get(url, stream=True) as r:
            r.raise_for_status()
            with open(f'./download/{local_filename}', 'wb') as f:
                for chunk in r.iter_content(chunk_size=8192):

         
                    print('Download')
                    f.write(chunk)
        print('download end')
        return local_filename

    except requests.exceptions.HTTPError as HttpError:
        print(HttpError)
        return 404
```

by default it's not possible because the program supports only 1 concurrent download, and for example, the program won't respond to other users until the previous download finishes. For this purpose I'm going to use the requests library, can you please show me an example of what should I do?

Comment: You already seem to be using `requests`, so it isn't clear what you are asking for help with.

Comment: It"s extremely clear what they're asking for, a way to download concurrently, i.e., non-blocking downloads.

Comment: There are plenty of examples on here of how to run a function using multiple threads, have you tried using any of these approaches?